# Retrieve teachers from User and Lesson models: an efficient way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models: User and Lesson.

```
User has_many :lessons
Lesson belongs_to :user
```

I have to retrieve User who are teachers (they have at least one lesson). Which is an efficient way?
For now I used a where condition that is traslated in a "IN" in Sql, so slow, or n query where n is the number of lessons. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want teachers, and teachers are users that have at least one lesson, then do this:

```
User.joins(:lessons)
```

That will perform an inner join thus excluding users that don't have any lessons.

But since a user can have multiple lessons, the returned table will potentially have multiple users. One solution for this could be to group by the users' ids.

```
User.joins(:lessons).group("users.id")
```

Or call `distinct`

```
User.joins(:lessons).distinct
```